# Running MySQL and Webrick at the same time Windows 7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Hopefully this is a simple problem to fix

I have installed the Ruby installer for windows, installed mysql 5.5 and have configured mysql to listen on port 3000

When I run the mysql server and then try to run webrick with rails s i get the error message

```
Only one usage of each socket is normally permitted bind(2)
```

So both servers are trying to run off the same port? I cannot use them both at the same time, if i kill the processes on localhost:3000 then both services are reset

is there a way of configuring these to both work at the same time?

EDIT

My config/database.yml file

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: library_development
pool: 5
username: root
password:
host: localhost
port: 3000
```

Has anyone come across this before, very frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -p flag to specify that webrick bind to a different port. Something like

```
rails server -p 3001 # Assuming you are starting via command prompt
```

That should allow both services to run simultaneously.

Comment: Ok so i have mysql running off port 3306 (default) and webrick running on port 3000, the issue i have here is now when i start the webrick server it cant connect to the MYSQL server

Comment: What does config/database.yml look like?  Make sure you updated the port there.

Comment: The port you specify here must be the port MySql is running on.  So in your case, 3306.

Comment: sorry about this, have changed but still get cant connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061) Mysql2 error)  would this have anything to do with the mysql2 gem?

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: nah that doesnt work, do i have to restart the mysql server for changes to take effect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20571/discussion-between-scott-s-and-richlewis)